# iOS location-based augmented reality toolkit/framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, augmented-reality, toolkit

is there any good free location-based augumented framework/api/toolkit for iOS? I tried Layar, but you can't change pretty much anything in the player itself so it's not worth much for me, I want to be able to alter the GUI for my needs. I also tried PanicAR from doPanic and the free version has watermarks all over the place. So again, is there anything else for iOS that is usable for free app if you want to alter the GUI yourself? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at mixare augmented reality engine! website: http://www.mixare.org Soruce code: https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone

It's open source software (GPLv3) henche you can use it, study the source code, modify it and make it better! :-)

HTH,
Daniele

Comment: This looks great. I would love to use this if it wasn't GPL'd!

Comment: Why is GPL an issue for you, Dolbz?

Comment: This one looks good! I'll definitelly give it a try and I'll hopefully come to some results :), thanks.

Comment: GPL is pretty much a non-starter if you want to sell any software that uses the library. I much prefer a license where the library and changes to it stay open source but your own code can remain closed (like LGPL or MIT)

Comment: GPL software can be sold, the license does not inhibits commercial usage of the sw. In the specific case you can build your own commercial launcher and use mixare only to display data. You would be free to use the license you want for your launcher, and if you need to adapt mixare only those modifications should be released as GPL software.